# Tweak Lucene scoring

Tags: java, lucene, scoring

I've had a look at the other Lucene scoring questions here but none seems to cover my problem.

I am indexing some large Word files. The lines in these files are split up and each 10 lines in the file is made into a Lucene `Document` (in fact they are overlapping 10-line `Documents`, but that's not relevant).

When I do a search on "bubble bloom" for example... what I find, to my slight surprise, that if one of these words occurs twice in a given `Document` it is counted pretty much as "just as good as" finding both search term words (i.e. "bubble" and "bloom") in the same `Document`.

Also a `Document` (set of 10 lines) containing 3 instances of the word "bubble" will be listed before a `Document` containing 1 x "bubble" and 1 x "bloom".  And one with 2 x "bubble" appears to be counted as equal to the `Document` with both words.

NB a `String` like this, "bubble bloom" will, it seems, be made into a `BooleanQuery` with two clauses by a `QueryParser.parse()`.

Is there any way to tweak things so that the fact of finding both words (search terms) in a `Document` ranks this `Document` higher than finding 2 or 3 instances of one of the words, but zero of the other?

PS incidentally, I just did a search where the search string was "+bubble +bloom"... obviously this excludes any `Document` where one word is missing.  But I see this as a sort of workaround.  I want the default functionality without the "+" (for "require") to score the fact of all terms being present higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is clear, that TF-IDF or BM25 scoring is very dependent on distribution of the terms in the index, since for example I was able to have document containing "bubble bloom" be higher than any of the docs, however that's most likely to my test distribution only

There are different ways to achieve this in a standard way. One of the very simplest way is to use **ConstantScoreQuery** which would always give you the score of 1.0 (or any other arbitrary number) for one or more matches of the term. In conjunction with **BooleanQuery** which is doing sum you could easily get documents scored according to the number of terms in the document.

E.g.

```
Query query = new BooleanQuery.Builder()
            .add(new ConstantScoreQuery(new TermQuery(new Term("text", "bloom"))), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .add(new ConstantScoreQuery(new TermQuery(new Term("text", "bubble"))), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD)
            .build();
```

This is still OR query, so you have matches with either of them. Obvious problem with this one is that match of **bubble** or **bloom** is equal. This probably have some caveats as well.

The link to the full code is [there](https://github.com/MysterionRise/information-retrieval-adventure/blob/master/lucene7/src/main/java/CustomScoring.java)